# Automatically restart computer when internet connection is lost

Tags: powershell

I have some trouble to do a script for Windows 10 that will check my internet connection every 2 minutes and restart the computer if it doesn’t find any connection.

I tried with PowerShell:

```
mainLoop() 
sleep 120
{
    if (!(Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Quiet)) {
        #Write-Host "Not connected"
        Restart-Computer
    } else {
        mainLoop()
    }
}
```

Do you have some advice to make it works?

Comment: Well - you're not looping for one.

Comment: Call your function in a `while($true)` loop and sleep after testing the connection if it's still connected, for starters.

Comment: `Restart-Computer` is somewhat drastic in response to a loss of connection -- isn't it?

Comment: I would `ping 192.168.1.1` first to check if it's not your router/modem needing a reboot. Also have a look at `netsh winsock reset` and `ipconfig` options for a faster/softer fix.

Answer (score 3):

Loop while the remote host is reachable, and restart once the loop terminates:

```
while (Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Quiet) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
}
Restart-Computer
```